# Reformatting array object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native

Sorry if this has been asked already but I'm pretty sure I'm close to the answer, and would appreciate a little help. The problem is getting the data object inside an array. example  data: [ {x:value,y:value} ]

(array data)
newCal Array {"comment": "W1", "date": "2020-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Anxious", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4}

```
//expected output
[
      {
        seriesName: 'emotion',
        data: [
          {x: 'date', y: rating},
          {x: 'date', y: rating},
        ],
      },
      {
        seriesName: 'emotion',
        data: [
          {x: 'date', y: rating},
          {x: 'date', y: rating},
        ],
      },
    ];
```

```
//code
 let sampleData= this.state.newCal.map(item => {
      const container = {};
      const container1 = {};

      container.seriesName = item.emotion;  
      container1.x = item.date;
      container1.y = item.rating;
      container.data = container1;

      return container;
  })
  console.log(usersByLikes);
```

```
//output

[
    {
        "data": 
            {"x": "2020-04-13", "y": "10"},
        "seriesName": "Anxious"
    }, 
    {
        "data": 
            {"x": "2020-04-13", "y": "10"},
        "seriesName": "Emotional"
    }
]
```

Comment: please provide this.state.newCal with few objects

Comment: you are pass an object here container.data = container1; container1 is not array; use container1 = []; then push objects into it or container.data =[]; container.data.push(container1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```js
const item = [{
    seriesName: 'emotion',
    date: '18-1-1995',
    rating: '5'
  },
  {
    seriesName: 'hey',
    date: '20-20-2020',
    rating: '3'
  },
  {
    seriesName: 'cool',
    date: '10-10-2010',
    rating: '3'
  },


]

let sampleData = item.map(item => {
  const container = {
    seriesName: item.seriesName,
    data: [{
      x: item.date,
      y: item.rating
    }]
  }
  return container
})

console.log(sampleData)
```

```
  /*
    0: {seriesName: "emotion", data: Array(1)}
    1: {seriesName: "hey", data: Array(1)}
    2: {seriesName: "cool", data: Array(1)}
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group them, use the first method.

If you just want to put x,y in array, use the second method.

```js
const newCal = [{"comment": "W1", "date": "2021-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Anxious", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4}, {"comment": "W1", "date": "2022-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Emotional", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4}, {"comment": "W1", "date": "2023-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Anxious", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4},{"comment": "W1", "date": "2024-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Anxious", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4},{"comment": "W1", "date": "2020-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Emotional", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4},{"comment": "W1", "date": "2020-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Anxious", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4},{"comment": "W1", "date": "2020-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Anxious", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4},{"comment": "W1", "date": "2020-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Emotional", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4},{"comment": "W1", "date": "2020-04-13", "day": 13, "emotion": "Anxious", "month": "4", "rating": "10", "rowid": 4}]


    
//first method to group data
const dataGroup ={} 
 
newCal.forEach(item => {
  if(!dataGroup[item.emotion]) dataGroup[item.emotion] = [];
  dataGroup[item.emotion].push({x: item.date, y: item.rating})
 })
 
 const sampleData = [];
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(dataGroup)) {
  sampleData.push({
    seriesName: key,
    data: value
  })
 }
 
console.log(sampleData)
 
 
 //second method just put x,y data in array
 //if you just want to put x,y in an array
 
 const sampleDataArray= newCal.map(item => ({
      seriesName: item.emotion,
      data: [{x: item.date, y: item.rating}]
  }))
  console.log(sampleDataArray);
```